# SeekBar update doesn't work

Tags: android, seekbar

I'm trying to create a video player in an Android application, and I want to update a SeekBar while the video is playing. Here's my code, in which the two first lines are in the OnCreate method:

```
seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(change);

private OnSeekBarChangeListener change = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    int progress = seekBar.getProgress();
    if (vv_video != null && vv_video.isPlaying()) {
        // Set the position of the currently playing
        vv_video.seekTo(progress);
    }
 }

 @Override
 public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

 }

 @Override
 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
             boolean fromUser) {

 }
};
```

And in Play method I tried the following:

```
protected void play(int msec) {
.....
     seekBar.setMax(vv_video.getDuration());
     // To update the progress bar thread, scale
     new Thread() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
             try {
                 isPlaying = true;
                 while (vv_video.isPlaying()) {
                     int current = vv_video.getCurrentPosition();
                     seekBar.setProgress(current);

                     sleep(500);
                 }
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }.start();
}
```

This doesn't work; while playing the video my seekBar is always at Position = 0.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you are trying to update the GUI thread from a different thread. What you will need to do is post a runnable to the GUI thread.

```
void play() {

    new Thread() {
        void run() {

            // Do stuff
            seekBar.post(new Runnable() {

                void run() {

                    // Update UI thread
                    seekBar.setProgress(10);
                }
            });
        }
    }.start();
}
```

You could also look into using a single handler for all postable messages.

[See this Android documentation.](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

Answer (score 0):

You must update seekbar in UI thread itself, and, this can be done using a runnable. Try this:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
//Make sure you update Seekbar on UI thread
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    if(mMediaPlayer != null){
        int mCurrentPosition = mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
        mSeekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);
    }
    mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
}
});
```